# How to unmarshal list of XML elements using Generics

Tags: java, jaxb

Does anyone know how to unmarshal a list of XML elements using Generics? This doesn't seem to work ...

```
xml = "<cats><cat><name>Ms. Piggy</name><city>Londen</city></cat><cat><name>Ms. Jerry</name><city>Londen</city></cat></cats>";

Processor pr = new Processor();
List<CatXML> cats = pr.xmlToObjectList( xml, CatXML.class);
```

Processor class:

```
public class Processor {
    public <T> List<T> xmlToObjectList(String xmlContainsObject, Class<T> objectType) {

        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectType);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlContainsObject);
            return (List<T>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Cat class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "cat")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CatXML implements Serializable {

    private String name = "";
    private String city = "";


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
}
```

I got an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"cats"). Expected elements are <{}cat>
at org.example.Processor.xmlToObjectList(Processor.java:90)
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"cats"). Expected elements are <{}cat>
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:701)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Processor` is expecting a list of elements, but your xml provide a `<cats>` tag. In my oppinion the best solution is to **deal with `<cats>` as an *Object***.

First, create the object that represents `<cats>`:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "cats")
public class CatList {

    @XmlElement(name = "cat")
    private List<CatXML> cats;

    public List<CatXML> getCats() {
        return cats;
    }
}
```

Then, change your `Processor` to deal with an *Object* instead of a `List`:

```java
public class Processor {
    public <T> T xmlToObject(String xml, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    }
}
```

Finally, change your main method:

```java
String xml = "<cats><cat><name>Ms. Piggy</name><city>Londen</city></cat><cat><name>Ms. Jerry</name><city>Londen</city></cat></cats>";
Processor pr = new Processor();

// Use CatList.class instead of CatXML.class
List<CatXML> cats = pr.xmlToObject(xml, CatList.class).getCats();
```

Now if you run:

```java
cats.forEach(cat -> System.out.printf("Name: %s - City: %s\n", cat.getName(), cat.getCity()));
```

You get:

```
Name: Ms. Piggy - City: Londen
Name: Ms. Jerry - City: Londen
```